# avr_bridge gen_avr.py / gen_avr_utils.py not working

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I have been trying to get the Hello World example working for avr_bridge. I run:

```
rosrun avr_bridge gen_avr.py callResponse.yaml .
```

in the example directory (as outlined). It crashes and I get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/user/ros-pkgs/avr_bridge/scripts/gen_avr.py", line 74, in <module>
    gen.generate(outputDir)
  File "/home/user/ros-pkgs/avr_bridge/src/gen_avr_utils.py", line 474, in generate
    self.generateMsgFile(inst_path, t)
  File "/home/user/ros-pkgs/avr_bridge/src/gen_avr_utils.py", line 450, in generateMsgFile
    write_header_file(f, msg_name, pkg, self.msg_specs[msg])
  File "/home/user/ros-pkgs/avr_bridge/src/gen_avr_utils.py", line 199, in write_header_file
    for field in msg_spec.parsed_fields():
AttributeError: 'MsgSpec' object has no attribute 'parsed_fields'
```

The avr_pos directory gets created and populated with a bunch of files, but the message file it builds, String.h, does not get fully written (I am guessing). I am using the latest avr_bridge from https://github.com/rutgers/avr_bridge as far as I know. Any help is appreciated.

Thanks.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/9980/avr_bridge-gen_avr.py-/-gen_avr_utils.py-not-working/) by [River](https://answers.ros.org/users/549/river/) on ROS Answers with karma: 66 on 2011-05-17

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I am not sure what is causing your error.  Could you try pulling the example project from my git repository?

Try taking :
https://github.com/rutgers/avr_bridge_callresponse

I just pulled a fresh copy of both avr_bridge and avr_bridge_callresponse from that repo and I am not getting that error.

---

Originally posted by [adasta](https://answers.ros.org/users/52/adasta/) with karma: 508 on 2011-06-19

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The issue ended up being the result of having an older installation of ROS conflicting with diamondback, which caused some unrelated issues.

Since then, avr_bridge has been deprecated and I have switched over to [rosserial](http://www.ros.org/wiki/rosserial).

---

Originally posted by [River](https://answers.ros.org/users/549/river/) with karma: 66 on 2011-10-21

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1